# Extract values from .dat file with fortran, with lines and especific variables

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran95

I need take te values of NPNOD, NELEM, and the others. and take the values of the next matrix

```
    $DIMENSIONES DEL PROBLEMA
    DIMENSIONES :  NPNOD= 27 ,      NELEM= 8 ,     NMATS= 1 ,     \
               NNODE= 8 ,      NDIME= 3 ,                         \ 
               NCARG= 1 , NGDLN= 3, NPROP= 5, \
               NGAUS= 1 , NTIPO= 1 , IWRIT= 1 ,\
               INDSO= 10 , NPRES= 9
    $---------------------------------------------------------
    GEOMETRIA 
    $ CONECTIVIDADES ELEMENTALES
    $ ELEM. MATER.    SECUENCIA DE CONECTIVIDADES
  1 1 8 6 12 20 18 15 23 25
  2 1 19 8 20 24 26 18 25 27
  3 1 5 2 6 8 14 11 15 18
  4 1 17 5 8 19 21 14 18 26
  5 1 7 4 9 13 8 6 12 20
  6 1 16 7 13 22 19 8 20 24
  7 1 3 1 4 7 5 2 6 8
  8 1 10 3 7 16 17 5 8 19
```

Comment: Welcome, please tak the [tour] and read [ask]. We need to see what you have tried so far and which specific problems you hit. Please show your code. If you didn't hit anything yet, you have to, this site cannot do the whole work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To read a mixture of Characters and numbers in fortran is done best by first reading the whole line into a character string and then to read the respective numerical values from this string. The details will depend a lot on the flexibility you need to have to deal with changing input formats. The more you can rely on the assumption that an input file will always be of identical structure the easier things get. 
You did not specify in your question the details of the 10 numbers in the rows numbered 1 to 8. Lets assume that the first number is the row of the matrix , the second number the number of the current matrix and the remaining eight numbers are the elements. Lets further assume that the elements in one row of the matrix will always be listed in one single input line.

```
character(len=5), dimension(10) :: fields
character(len=80) :: string
character(len=1024) :: grand
integer, dimension(10) :: values
fields(1) = 'NPNOD'  ! and so on ... 
read(unit=ird, '(a)', iostat=ios) string     ! read line 'DIMENSIONES...'
read(unit=ird, '(a)', iostat=ios) string     ! read dummy string   
grand(1:80) = string                         ! place into grand total
read(unit=ird, '(a)', iostat=ios) string     ! read dummy string
grand(81:160) = string                       ! append to grand total
...! repeat for three more lines
grand(len_trim(grand)+1:len_trim(grand)+1) = ',' ! Append a final comma
do i=1,10                                    ! Loop over all field names
  ilen = len_trim(field(i))                  ! store length of field name, may vary?
  ipos = index(grand, field(i))              ! Find start of field name
  icom = index(grand(ipos+ilen+1:len(grand), ',')       ! locate trailing comma
  read(grand(ipos+ilen+1:ipos+ilen+icom-1),*) values(i) ! Read numerical value
enddo
read(unit=ird, '(a)', iostat=ios) string     ! read dummy string
read(unit=ird, '(a)', iostat=ios) string     ! read dummy string
read(unit=ird, '(a)', iostat=ios) string     ! read dummy string
do i= 1, values(2)     ! if NELEM is in fields(2)
  read(ird, *) irow, imat, (array(i,j),j=1, values(2)) ! read leading two no's and elements
enddo
```

You still have to define the integer variables, ird, ilen, ipos, icom, irow, imat, ios, i, j, the matrix array or the many matrices you need to read. 
Upon a read the value of the status variable ios should be inspected...

Essentially I do:
define a character variable field with all the names 'NPNOD' ...
read and concatenate the lines 'dimensiones' until 'INDSO' into the string "grand"
Loop over all field and
  detect position of the field name and the position of the trailing comma
  read from the grand string the subsection that contains only the numerical value
Loop over the rows with matrix elements to read the two first numbers and the matrix elements.
As I appended a final comma, that is missing in the line 'INDSO...', the loop over the field names does not have to bother with the special case of 'NPRES', which does not have a trailing comma in the original input file. 
Your actual code should 
  check if there are never more than 10 fields
  is 80 character the maximum length of any individual input line
  will 1024 characters be neough for the concatenated list.

Comment: A friendly advice: It is great to have another person who answers questions, but it is not worth your time to answer *this* kind of questions. First, it is quite possible the questioner won't come back to actually read your answer, or that they will never accept it. Especially when they do not respond to comments.. Second, it is very likely the answer will be deleted together with the question. The questions to be answerd, instead to be voted to be closed, should really follow at least some basic points [ask].